# What is the geometry of the universe in "The Wall of Darkness" by Arthur C Clarke?

Tags: space, arthur-c-clarke

*The Wall of Darkness* by Arthur C. Clarke (1949) is a piece of Math fiction, usually quoted in semi-academic circles as illustrating the geometry of the [Moebius band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip).

It deals with a universe with a single sun and planet but no other stars.  The world supposedly always stayed light, with only a slight
change with the sun dipping toward the horizon a bit in winter.
Their planet has an inhospitably hot north, a temperate
middle, and an extremely cold south.  The south is barren, except for an
insurmountable wall that stretches across the world at a point so far
south that people can barely reach it during the summer, when things
warm up.

There is a rumor that seeing what is on the other side of the wall
will make a man go mad.  But a curious, wealthy guy named Shervane decides he just has to do it anyway.  In a massive project that takes more than 7 years, he
has a series of platforms built, and he walks up on the wall, making sure his friend will blow everything up if something horrible happens.

Then he walks away from the sun, which is dimming behind him as he
walks, and in front of him another sun appears and grows bright.  As he
approaches the edge of the wall, he sees his friend (whom he left behind)
peering up at him.

Then they blow up the platforms, so that no one else can ever try to
breach the wall again, saying it was necessary.  He imagines in his mind
another him blowing up the platform on the other side, but says of
course that is impossible, since he is the only man in the world who
knows for sure that the WALL HAS ONLY ONE SIDE.

The geometry of the Moebius strip is explained in the story as well, through a Professor of the protagonist.

But of course, as the author must have known well, the Mobius strip is two dimensional and any model of the universe (in his story) has to be three dimensional.

Now a [Klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle) is usually regarded as a higher dimensional equivalent of the Moebius band. While this in clearly a misconception (the Klein "bottle" is a two dimensional surface, just like the Moebius strip, only it *seems* to enclose a volume unlike the other), it could well be that the model involved here is the "inside" of the Klein bottle, or, equivlently, that the universe has the Klein bottle for its boundary. But it fails me to recognise how exactly the "wall situation" works with a universe in such a shape.

It has been suggested that the wall is built on the neck of the bottle. But a glance at the figure will show that a person who walks "across the top" of such a wall shall see just the region beyond, not the same side. The property of the Klein bottle (analogous to Moebius band having only one side and not two) is that it has only one of the parities left and right, and only one of inside and outside. For our wall to work in the intended way, it has to "go through" the "surface" connecting the false inside and false outside, which does not make any sense.

It has also been commented that the story is trying to sound more impressive than it actually is. But it could be just that the author intended no more than a mood piece focusing on the philosophy of our existence and our search into "the great unknown."

Can anyone point what the proper geometry of this universe is? Which means to recognise which known mathematical shape - a three dimensional surface - models it accurately.

The summary of the story and the comments given above are copied from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rec.arts.sf.science/mk1aOafclLU/C2KBRZxRJSoJ).

EDIT: We allow branched 3D surfaces as well when we say 3D surface, which seems necessary in view of the discussion following Kyle Jones' answer.

Comment: If anyone wants to check it out, the whole story is currently readable on google books starting at http://books.google.com/books?id=HLz1g95AXDsC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA104

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**tl;dr The manifold surrounding Shervane's universe is called an [Alice handle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_handle).**

To simplify the explanation and ease visualization, imagine that our hero Shervane is a two-dimensional being who lives on a finite 2D surface, a circular region cut out of a plane.  Viewed from above Shervane looks like the letter R as he moves around his world.  Looking down we see Shervane sliding toward the edge of his world and oblivion.  To save him, we add a long strip of space to the edge of his universe so that when he reaches the old edge he won't soar off into nothingness.  We bend the strip around gently in the third dimension so that it connects back to the edge of disk where it started.  Shervane's universe is now (roughly) a disk with a cylinder against its edge.  Now if Shervane keeps walking he traverses the outside of the cylinder and eventually ends up back where he started except moving in the opposite direction.

Unfortunately, the trip through the third dimension has also flipped Shervane so that he is now his own mirror image.  From above he now looks like the letter Я instead of R.  His left is everyone else's right and vice versa.  To keep Shervane from being flipped, we add a half twist to the strip we stuck to the edge of the disk so that Shervane gets an additional flip before he returns to the disk.

That half twist we added converts the strip we added into a Moebius strip, so now Shervane's universe looks like a disk with its edge tangent to the surface of a Mobius strip, this instead of a disk against a cylinder.  To prevent Shervane from walking off the disk in another direction, we must surround the whole disk with these twisted strips.  We also must glue the strip edges together so he can't walk off those edges.  If you glue the edges of a Moebius strip together, you get the [Klein surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle).  So if Shervane lived in Flatland, in order to make the story work his flat disk would have to have its edges surrounded by and tangent to a unified Klein surface.  (If we didn't care about reversing Shervane's left and right, a disk with its entire edge tangent to the surface of torus would suffice.)

To make the story work in a three-dimensional universe, Shervane's universe would have to be surrounded by not a Klein surface but rather whatever the 3D analog of Klein surface is.  **The term for such a manifold is an [Alice handle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_handle) or non-orientable wormhole.**

Comment: The wiki article leads to an article about Alice Universes. Which seems to imply that the universe of the story is an Alice Universe. If so, the physics of an Alice Universe is mindblowing - matter are either matter or antimatter depending on direction of travel!

Comment: But would a 3D analog of a Klein surface actually work? A flatlander living on a 2D Klein bottle wouldn't find that there was some boundary where, as they got close to the boundary, they'd come face to face with a mirror duplicate of themselves. From the page at http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~teach95/sos95/big-picture/ the tiling for a gluing diagram of a klein bottle looks like this: http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~teach95/sos95/big-picture/2k.tile.gif ...nowhere do you see an R facing its own mirror image.

Comment: I guess the story doesn't say he met his own mirror image, but rather he walked along the wall for some time and came back to his friend. Still, for that to work in a Klein surface wouldn't he have to walk the whole length of the finite universe (a single tile in a tiling diagram)? I suppose you could imagine that the Sun was actually very small, and the planet itself a walkable size, and a sort of cylindrical shape so it could join up with itself on two faces of a gluing diagram like the one at http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~teach95/sos95/big-picture/3k.glue.gif

Comment: Incidentally, the 3D gluing diagram in my last comment can be referred to as a "1/2-twist torus", see http://books.google.com/books?id=KhTJZG-U3ssC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA167 ...I also see some other pages on topology that use the phrase  "twisted torus" for topologies like this, in 2D or 3D (i.e. take the gluing diagram for a 2-torus or 3-torus and flip or rotate one of the edges or faces). I would guess that an Alice handle falls into this category, since in 2D many authors seem to treat "Klein bottle" and "twisted torus" as synonymous, but I can't find a gluing diagram for an Alice Handle.

Comment: Having read the story at http://books.google.com/books?id=HLz1g95AXDsC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA104 , I don't actually think this answer is right--the way Clarke describes it, he doesn't walk along the wall parallel to its edge, but rather perpendicular, until he comes to the other edge and sees the mirror image of the stairs (and it's not a long walk, while his planet is huge). Clarke also implies that before the wall, people went mad--implying not just that they looped around the world and found their home with left/right reversed, but that they could actually walk right up to their own mirror images.

Comment: So I think to capture how it works in the story, you'd need something more like a space where matter repeats in a way that involves mirror surfaces, like the patterns shown at http://epinet.anu.edu.au/mathematics/orbifold_notation and http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/doyle/mpls/handouts/node30.html and https://www.ma.utexas.edu/smmg/archive/2012/Perutz/PerutzSlides.pdf (see p. 17 especially) and apparently described using "orbifolds"...I don't think such mirror joins are possible in topological space defined by identifying faces of a cube in *pairs* (a mirror face must be identified with itself!)

Comment: @Hypnosifl He climbs *up* on the wall using the apparatus, but then walks *across* its top, isn't it, having essentially the same consequence as walking across in the absence of the wall (assuming this height dimension is infinite)? And what he sees is described as neither an *image* nor a *mirror* image in the literal sense,but he essentially returns to where he started. The matter he sees is the same that was there.

Comment: @Hypnosifl This is exactly what would happen if you travel towards the erstwhile edge of Kile Jones' circular-disc-augmented-with-the-bounding-Klein-bottle from its centre - you walk along a ray from the centre, but the ray converges on itself as you cover the erstwhile edge, with the effect that end up where you started (and without inverting left and right). This is for the 2D model, I don't know how to describe the 3D model more than Jones did.

Comment: @N Unnikrishnan - I didn't mean "image" in a purely visual sense, I meant that without the wall he'd actually be able to run into an apparent physical copy of himself who mirrored all his movements. I don't really understand the explanation about curving the strip (a visual would help), but the standard mathematical way to describe topological spaces is with a "gluing diagram" that tells you which edges of a finite shape connect, see http://plus.maths.org/content/space-do-all-roads-lead-home for a basic intro and the page at http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~teach95/sos95/big-picture/ for more detail.

Comment: Clarke has another story where a person gets flipped left to right in an accident.  He starts to starve because he can't asslimilate asymmetric chemicals like proteins properly....

Comment: @slebetman - well, this rift is very localized on this planet, as the distance around it is very short...walking distance.  Since this is a primitive society, you don't know how far this effect extends above the wall, off the planet...

Comment: @Hypnosifl: The story doesn't mention that people will see duplicates of themselves. Merely that they go mad. Like, when you see Cthulhu you go mad but that doesn't mean Cthulhu creates duplicates of you. Besides, twins meet their duplicates all the time and they don't go mad.

Comment: @Oldcat: In this universe, all the matter exist only on this planet and its sun. Therefore this rift "bisects" a large percentage of matter in this universe. So yes, it's localized. But that's like saying that the galactic cluster that our Milky Way belong to is "local".

Comment: @Hypnosifl: Indeed, now that I think about it, the story implies that people will not see mirror images of themselves. If so he should have seen himself or his assistant and himself. Instead he only sees his assistant.

Comment: The physics of Alice Universes means that it makes sense for its inhabitants to build such a wall. Otherwise, traversing the "twist/border/handle" will convert you from matter into anti-matter (or vice versa) thus if you make an excursion to the other side your anti-atoms will annihilate anything you touch.

Comment: It could also be that mild exposure to the "other side" may damage a person's brain enough to make him go mad (not to mention giving him via massive amounts of severely damaged DNA)

Comment: @slebetman - The area guarded by the wall can't convert matter to antimatter - the atmosphere would be explosive, and the man would blow up when he started heading back

Comment: @Oldcat "Clarke has another story..." I suspect you mean *The Plattner Story* by H G Wells (1896).

Comment: @NUnnikrishnan - Nope. *Technical Error* : The first power plant to exploit superconductivity has been built and worker Richard Nelson is "laterally inverted" following an accidental short-circuit in the facility. Nelson finds himself wearing his wedding ring on the wrong hand, written texts appear mirror-inverted and coins and his technical diary have been affected. Nelson begins to starve; normal food does not nourish him sufficiently due to its spatial structure. A chemist, Prof. Vandenburg, develops mirror-inverted parallels of substances required by Nelson.

Comment: @slebetman - since the two "copies" of the stairway were one and the same, it must have been true that at the moment he was ascending "his" stairway a "duplicate" of him was ascending the other, at the moment he started walking across the top his "duplicate" did too--for example, if at the moment he stepped on the top he aimed a powerful telescope at the location of the "other" stairway he should have seen himself peering back through a telescope, no?

Comment: @slebetman - ...if it was really a Klein-like topology seeing your duplicate wouldn't imply you should meet, because there'd be a hall-of-mirrors effect with multiple stairways, and as you headed towards "his" stairway he'd head towards a different stairway than the one you just came from. But it doesn't really make sense as such a topology because Clarke implies the ancients built the wall here because this spot was "special" in that one only had to walk a short distance to loop around--in any topology where opposite cube faces are glued you'd have to go the same distance in any direction.

Comment: You guys should take the discussion to chat; the moderators are going to wipe most of this, I fear.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: There is only one stairway, there are no two stairways. Just as the assistant is the same person on the other side. The stairway on the other side is the same stairway on "this" side. Not a duplicate.

Comment: @slebetman - I know there is only one stairway, but any predictions about what happens in a closed space whose topology can be represented by a gluing diagram of a square or cube are exactly equivalent to what happens in a diagram where you "tile" an infinite space with multiple copies of everything in that square/cube (with the edges/faces connected up the right way). Did you look at the pages http://plus.maths.org/content/space-do-all-roads-lead-home and http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~teach95/sos95/big-picture/ that I linked to in the first comment of mine you responded to?

Comment: @slebatman - for example, from the second page, the gluing diagram for a 2D Klein bottle is http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~teach95/sos95/big-picture/2kR.glue.gif and you can determine exactly what happens if you take any path in that space by looking at the equivalent tiling diagram http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~teach95/sos95/big-picture/2k.tile.gif with multiple "duplicate" R's. Similarly for a 2D torus compare http://plus.maths.org/issue10/features/topology/buzz.gif with http://plus.maths.org/issue10/features/topology/bees.gif

Comment: @Kyle Jones - I hope they don't, it's all relevant to the question of whether a Klein-bottle-like topology is compatible with the story's description of a huge world where, in one particular spot, you can walk a relatively short distance in a straight line and loop around the space back to where you started (I don't think it is). And the question was specifically about what kind of *mathematical* structure could be used to explain what happens in the story. In any case, on this site I always get an error when I try clicking the "take this discussion to chat" link.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I worked on the details of the construction a bit in the answer; hopefully it is easier for you to visualize.  In particular, the whole universe isn't meant to be a Klein surface analog but rather be surrounded by and tangent to such an analog.

Comment: @Kyle Jones - in the first case without the twist it seems to me that what you're describing isn't a manifold at all, because if you "bend the strip around gently in the third dimension so that it connects back to the edge of disk where it started" then the edge of the disc would be connected to both the top and bottom edge of the strip, so the surface would "branch" there...a 2D manifold has to have the property that the local neighborhood of every point is topologically equivalent to an open circle in a 2D Euclidean space. Am I misunderstanding or are you not trying to describe a manifold?

Comment: @Kyle Jones ...in effect, in that first case without the twist it sounds like you're stitching the edge of a circular disc to the "inner equator" of a torus shown in this diagram: http://www.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/inner.equator.png (from the page http://www.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/geodesics.xhtml ). Is that what you're imagining? If so, is the second case basically similar, but sewing the edge of a disc to some closed curve in a Klein bottle space?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yes, there's a branch at the disk edge in both the twisted and untwisted boundaries and I have no idea how it would be resolved in such a universe.  Systems of particles bound by molecular and nuclear forces (e.g. bodies, clothes) might be assumed to hang together and head down the same branch as a unit.  Free particles (e.g. air, photons, cosmic rays) I assume would take both paths with equal probability.

Comment: @Hypnosifl "in effect, in that first case without the twist it sounds like you're stitching the edge of a circular disc to the 'inner equator' of a torus"... Yes, exactly right to both questions.

Comment: @Kyle Jones - as I said this wouldn't qualify as a "manifold", not sure if that's what the OP meant by "three dimensional surface" though. Another issue: if you were standing near the branch wouldn't you see light coming at you from both halves, and get a double image? It's also not clear to me why gluing a disc to a closed line in a Klein space (or gluing the surface of a sphere to a closed 2D surface in the 3D analogue of a Klein space) would result in a wall with one side--would the wall be straddling the branch, or wholly in the Klein bottle space, or wholly in the disc/sphere space?

Comment: Likewise, would the surface of the planet (not counting the wall, imagine the surface before the wall was built) lie wholly within the disc/sphere, wholly within the Klein space, or would it straddle the two? If it straddled them, would it branch into two different planetary surfaces as well?

Comment: @Hypnosifl If you're on the disk looking toward the branch you should see a single image since photons make the circuit both directions and recombine.  If you're in the branch, your back will block some of the photons and others will have different flight times and paths to your eye.  The story skirted the issue in both cases by making the view dim as you move along the branch; some kind of energy absorption (leakage?) was happening... don't know how to do that with just topology.

Hmmm, that's a good question about wall!  I'll have to think about that.

Comment: @Kyle Jones - I agree they'd recombine if you're on the disc, but what I meant was they'd recombine into what looks like a superimposed version of two different images, each showing whatever's in your line of sight near you on that part of the branch. For example if your friend Alice is standing in front of you on one branched space, and Bob is standing in front of you on the other branched space, you'd be getting photons from both of them coming from the same direction, so you'd see a single superimposed image of Alice and Bob.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I guess that would explain the reports of madness and also explain why Wiser Heads built the wall in the first place.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Even though I meant a manifold initially, it now seems to me that we can't do this with one and we'll have to enlarge the definition of 3D surface to include branches as well. Jones construction seems to be the simplest model.

Comment: @KyleJones "Systems of particles...head down the same branch as a unit. Free particles...would take both paths with equal probability." Is this pretty well known, or will these make interesting questions on Physics.SE? After all, why should our universe be bound by a manifold, i.e., why should there be no branching?

Comment: @N Unnikrishnan - I've been playing around with this on scratch paper and I think it can be done on a particular manifold, although with some weird assumptions: I imagine the surface of the planet is shaped like a torus and the one-sided wall is on the inner equator, and it's impossible to travel in a loop around the inner equator without climbing the wall because the land the wall is built on is bounded by an uncrossable ocean (or some other barrier distinct from the wall itself) on either side. Explaining it would require some 3D gluing/tiling diagrams but I can try if you're interested.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Sure, make it an answer and we shall discuss it there.

Answer (score 2):

@N Unnikrishnan wrote in the comments above: "I imagine the surface of the planet is shaped like a torus and the one-sided wall is on the inner equator". I don't think this is true, because:

1. Shervane’s world was "turning the same face always toward its solitary sun". (Clarke calls this side of the world the "north") Then it must make a revolution around the sun and around its axis in the same time, just like the Moon around the Earth.
2. "journey over land and sea... could be shortened no more than a little by traveling as far north as one dared." This means that the north, the smaller the circumference of this world.
3. based on 1 and 2, I assume that from the wall to the north pole the this world is hemisphere or something like that. I don’t understand how to explain the change of seasons in this model. But in a model with a torus, this seems to me an even more difficult task.
4. as for the southern border of this world, if you replace the disk with a hemisphere, I like your idea.
5. Could it be that in the area where the wall was erected, the planet is in contact with the boundary of this universe?

Comment: You’ve written this in reply to a comment but it does seem to be an answer somewhat. It would be better if you [edit]ed this to read more as an answer.

Comment: Nice points. But by the way, I didn't make this comment, somebody else - the user @Hypnosifl - did. Just like you, I don't agree much with the idea. The "@N Unnikrishnan" at the beginning of the comment signifies that he is notifying me. The name of the author of the comment will be displayed at the end of the comment as a clickable link.

Answer (score 1):

In both a Moebius Strip and Klein bottle, the "twist" and reconnection are in a higher dimension.  The strip is 1D, and the bottle is 2D.  It is a mistake to think the bottle goes "through" itself.  A true Klein bottle has no hole, as opposed to the physical picture we see.

To make a region of 3D space "have no other side" you need to bend space itself and connect it twisted backward in higher dimensions.  If you do that, you find yourself at the origin point eventually without turning around.

You can't make even a Klein Bottle properly, so there is no true representation of this space any more than there is for a tesseract, the 4-D analog of a cube.

Comment: The question wasn't really about whether we can "represent" it in ordinary 3D space, just whether any "known mathematical shape - a three dimensional surface - models it accurately".

Comment: No normal 3D space can do this. Actually even a Mobius Strip isn't an exact analogue because on a strip you do not retrace your path until you reach the origin point. In the case of the wall, space twists you into a 180 degree turn and you end up walking back along your path to the origin.

Comment: A Moebius strip is not 1D. A line is a 1D object. A flat plane is 2D. While a Moebius strip has only one side and one edge, the strip as whole is a 3D object.

Comment: @Stan,  the ideal strip is 2d, twisted in 3d.

Comment: @Oldcat - what do you mean by "normal" 3D space though? Are there any topologies of 3D space that are mathematically well-defined but which wouldn't be included in this category?

Comment: @Dima Understand that.  Certainly not 1D and once twisted it is no longer 2D.  While we construct with paper, is described mathematically in 3D space.

Comment: @Stan What Dima points out is that, in mathematics, an object is called 2D if it "has no thickness", however complicated it folds/twists making it unable to be visualised (*embedded*, in math terms) in anything less than a space of 3, 4 or 5 dimensions. By the way, a celebrated result in Algebraic Topology (the Whitney Embedding Theorem) says that any such ("nice") object of n dimensions can be embedded for sure in space of dimension 2n+1, and nothing less than that may be sufficient. So 2D surfaces can require up to 5D for visualisation.

Comment: @N Unnikrishnan Thanks for the clarification, I stand corrected.  Should have never dropped that class in Algebraic Topology many years ago :)

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Sure. For an analogy, go to 2D, where the universe is assumed to be a plane.  There, the angles of a triangle add to 180, and one parallel line can be drawn through a point near a line.  But if the universe is a sphere, angles of a triangle are greater than 180, and no parallel lines can be found.  If you walk in any direction, you eventually come back home.  If the 2D verse is saddle shaped, you can draw many parallel lines, and triangles add to less than 180.  These are three entirely self consistent geometries - Euclidean and 2 non-Euclidean.  Extend the same idea to 3D

Comment: @Oldcat - spatial curvature is different than topology, though. Do you agree that even with a strictly Euclidean space (where angles of a triangle add up to 180 and only one parallel line can be drawn through a point near another line), it is possible to choose different compact topologies, like a torus or a Klein bottle? It seems to me we need some non-trivial topology to explain the story, specifically a non-orientable one where there can be no global definition of left and right (because the left side of the wall must become the right side).